# How to delete data of recentTaskInfo?

Tags: android, process, task

I have already kill the background processes, but in the `recentTaskInfo` still exist activity information. I know processes and activity back stack is different,but don't know how to remove activity from this stack.

Answer (score 0):

remove activity from this stack.

Just Use

```
MyActivity.this.finish();
```

For more info Refer this Link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29

**EDIT**

Everything with regard to Tasks and Back stacks in Android, including your question, can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html.

Comment: I am realizing that open recent tasks, click a button, kill the process, and empty the activity stack.so what u said haven't helped yet.